# Spring WebFlux: Merge Mono and Flux / Put Mono into Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm wondering if it is possible to put the value of a `Mono` as a value into a `Flux` just like you could append any object to a list. I know there are some methods you could use but none of them fulfills my exact purpose. What I tried so far:

```
Flux<T> flux;
Mono<T> mono;
Flux.merge(flux, mono); // <- returns Flux<Object>
```

This doesn't sound too bad but notice that it does not return `Flux<T>` as I would need it but `Flux<Object>`. Same with `Flux.concat(flux, mono);`. The method `Flux.zip(flux, mono);` would stop merging as soon as the Mono completes as far as I understand.

Has somebody a solution for this?

Comment: You can use `flatMapMany` to convert the mono into a flux and then do the merge. It depends on what you have in your Mono, and what you want in the end, a Flux?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have a Mono of a certain type, ExtendedResourceModel in my case. Now I would like to get a Flux of the exact same type. I tried using `flatMapMany`on my Mono and it does seem to be what I need, except I do not want to actually map the object as the type is already correct. I will try using `null`as mapper function here. When I merge both Fluxes now I get `Flux<Object>`as the return type. Why is that?

Comment: Please dont write in the comment, update your question to be more clear on your intentions. Stack overflow is not a forum, its a Q&A site. Null is not allowed in reactive streams. This is covered in the reactor getting started section of the reference documentation.

Comment: You seemed to need clarification so I just wanted to answer your question and did so in a comment to get you notified. The original post already states what I would like to have in the end (quote: _notice that it does not return Flux<T> **as I would need it**_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:
[image]

I have the method return a Flux of the desired type which in my case was an 'ExtendedResourceModel'. I create a Mono of this type which gets initialized by another method that I commented out to keep this answer as concise as possible. If a certain condition is met I want to also use a Flux from a different source so I use 'Flux.concat()' to put all elements into a single Flux. The 'concat'-method works by subscribing to the first argument, letting it finish, subscribing to the second one and so on.
In case of my condition not being met I just use 'concat' again but this time with only the Mono which will put the Mono's element into a new Flux. This way both cases have the same return type.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to do, if you need to do that you can convert your Flux to mono

Mono monoToFlux = flux.collectList();

Mono mono;

Mono.zip (mono, monoToFlux).flatmap(tuple -> {
... more code ...
})

Comment: Please provide an answer in english, with correctly formatted code, this is not spanish stack overflow.

Comment: Also, the user is doing a merge using a Flux so i assume its a Flux he wants in the end, not a Mono.